# AMQP convertSendAndReceive fails moving from Spring Boot 1.5 to 2

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, migration

I'm migrating code from Spring Boot 1.5.x to 2.0.3.RELEASE.

It uses RabbitMQ to make an RPC style call to a set of remote engines using the `convertSendAndReceive(...)` method.

All works fine in 1.5, but fails in the migrated code.

The logging initially shows

```
SimpleConsumer [queue=amq.rabbitmq.reply-to, consumerTag=amq.ctag-39fo5C1y6q8J9OevWDN3_A identity=6ffebba9] started
```

The message reaches the engine and is handled correctly.

However, the return value is empty and the following is logged

```
ERROR o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate No correlation header in reply
```

In 1.5 we didn't add a correlation Id to the caller. Do we now need to or is there something else we need to do?

TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [the Spring amqp docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/#request-reply)

> With versions earlier than verion 2.0, the RabbitTemplate created a new consumer for each request and canceled the consumer when the reply was received (or timed out). Now, the template uses a DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer instead, allowing the consumers to be reused; the template still takes care of correlating the replies so there is no danger of a late reply going to a different sender. If you want to revert to the previous behavior, set property useDirectReplyToContainer (direct-reply-to-container when using XML configuration) to false.

So for example...

```
    rabbitTemplate.setUseDirectReplyToContainer(false);
```